# S4 object creation in R

Tags: r, object, r-s4

I am busy with comparing different machine learning techniques in R.
This is the case: I made several functions that, in an automated way
are able to create each a different prediction model (e.g: logistic regression, random forest, neural network, hybrid ensemble , etc.) , predictions, confusion matrices, several statistics (e.g AUC and Fscore) ,and different plots.

Now I would like to create a list of S4 (or S3?) objects in R, where each object contains the model, predictions, the plots, confusion matrix , auc and fscore.

The idea is that each function creates such object and then append it to the object list in the return statement.

How should I program such class? And how can I define that each model can be of some different type (I suppose that all models that I create are S3 objects, so how do can I define this in my S4  class?

The end result should be able to do something like this: modelList[i]@plot should for example summon the requested plot. and names(modelList[i]) should give the name of the used model (if this is not possible, modelList[i]@name will do). Also, it should be possible to select the best model out of the list, based on a parameter, such as AUC.
I am not experienced in creating such object, so this is the code / idea I have at the moment:

```
 modelObject <- setClass(
  # Set the name for the class
  "modelObject",

  # Define the slots
  slots = c(
    modelName = "character"
    model = #should contain a glm, neural network, random forest , etc model
    predictions = #should contain a matrix or dataframe of custid and prediction
    rocCurve = #when summoned, the ROC curve should be plotted
    plotX = #when summoned, plot X should be plotted
    AUC = "numeric" #contains the value of the AUC
    confusionMatrix = "matrix" #prints the confusion matrix in the console
    statX = "numeric"#contains statistic X about the confusion matrix e.g. Fscore
  ),
  # Set the default values for the slots. (optional)
  prototype=list(
    # I guess i can assign NULL to each variable of the S4 object
  ),

  # Make a function that can test to see if the data is consistent.
  # This is not called if you have an initialize function defined!
  validity=function(object)
  {
    #not really an idea how to handle this
    }
    return(TRUE)
  }
)
```

Comment: Relevant: [1](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html), [2](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s4Classes.html), [3](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is for each slot you want in your `modelObject` class, determine the range of expected values. For example, your `model` slot has to support all the possible classes of objects that can be returned by model training functions (e.g. lm(), glm(), nnet(), etc.). In the example case, you see the following objects returned:

```

```
x <- y <- 1:10
class(lm(x~y))
class(glm(x~y))
class(nnet(x~y, size=10))
```

```

Since there is no common class among the objects returned, it might make more sense to use an S3, which has less rigorous syntax and would allow you to assign various classes of output to the same field name. Your question is actually quite tough to answer, given that there are so many different approaches to take with R's myriad OO systems.

Comment: I am now experimenting with the S3 class creation. I will give an update soon. Is it also possible to store plots in S3?

Comment: Is this a correct approach? 
`modelObject <- function(modelName , modelObject, modelPredictions , rocCurve , plotX , aUC , confusionMatrix , statX)
{
  
  modelObject <- list(
    model.name = modelName,
    model.object = modelObject,
    model.predictions = modelPredictions,
    roc.curve = rocCurve,
    plot.x = plotX,
    roc.auc = aUC,
    confusion.matrix = confusionMatrix,
    stat.x = statX
    
  )
  
  ## Set the name for the class
  class(modelObject) <- append(class(modelObject),"model")
  return(modelObject)
}`

Comment: The code is working. But now  i am encountering a new problem. I will open a new threat for that problem as it is different from this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Use `setOldClass()` to promote each S3 class to it's S4 equivalent

```
setOldClass("lm")
setOldClass(c("glm", "lm"))
setOldClass(c("nnet.formula", "nnet"))
setOldClass("xx")
```

Use `setClassUnion()` to insert a common base class in the hierarchy

```
setClassUnion("lmORnnetORxx", c("lm", "nnet", "xx"))

.ModelObject <- setClass("ModelObject", slots=c(model="lmORnnetORxx"))

setMethod("show", "ModelObject", function(object) {
    cat("model class: ", class(object@model), "\n")
})
```

In action:

```
> library(nnet)
> x <- y <- 1:10
> .ModelObject(model=lm(x~y))
model class:  lm 
> .ModelObject(model=glm(x~y))
model class:  glm lm 
> .ModelObject(model=nnet(x~y, size=10, trace=FALSE))
model class:  nnet.formula nnet
```

I think that you would also like to implement a `Models` object that contains a list where all elements are `ModelObject`; the constraint would be imposed by a validity method (see `?setValidity`).

Comment: Wow, so if i'm understanding it right, with this code i can create with this code an unified .ModelObject class, which i can use as class or object in my  code: 

`slots = c(
    modelName = "character"
    model = #should contain a glm, neural network, random forest , etc model
    predictions = #should contain a matrix or dataframe of custid and prediction
    rocCurve = #when summoned, the ROC curve should be plotted
    plotX = #when summoned, plot X should be plotted
   
  ),` 

How can i implement a plot in this object?

Comment: The lattice and ggplot2 packages return objects that have an (S3) class that can be stored in a similar way -- `setOldClass()` + `setClassUnion()`. But maybe you mean that you would like to write a method for the (S3) plot generic. You could do this with `plot.ModelObject <- function(x, y, ...) {}`.

Comment: I am currently busy with an S3 object (see comment on the other answer to this question) , I think the S3 approach is more intuitive. I will test it on my code asap